# Optimizing Langton's Ant in Python

Tags: python, optimization, graphics

I'm using graphics.py in Python to create a really simple [Langton's Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) program. My issue is that the ant takes more than 2 minutes and 30 seconds to "highway." I'd love for this to be reduced to just a few seconds if possible.

I've already tried "optimizing" my code (cut from ~90 lines to ~45 lines, mostly just compacting a bunch of if statements). That shaved about 10 seconds off, so I'm guessing the issue is the actual rendering. I really want to be able to see the ant trace its path about the screen, but I fear the issue is drawing each pixel black or white.

Here's the main block of my current code:

```
#Import graphics.py and math, initialize variables

grid = [[0 for x in range(xSize)] for y in range(ySize)]  # 0 is white, 1 is black

while key != 'x':
    key = win.checkKey()
    if grid[antX][antY] == 0: #Light square
        if antDir < 4: #Turn ant right
            antDir += 1
        else:
            antDir = 1
        grid[antX][antY] = 1
        win.plotPixel(antX, antY, "black")
    elif grid[antX][antY] == 1: #Dark square
        if antDir > 1: #Turn ant left
            antDir -= 1
        else:
            antDir = 4
        grid[antX][antY] = 0
        win.plotPixel(antX, antY, "white")
    if antDir == 1 and antY != 0:
        antY -= 1
    elif antDir == 2 and antX != xSize-1:
        antX += 1
    elif antDir == 3 and antY != ySize-1:
        antY += 1
    elif antDir == 4 and antX != 0:
        antX -= 1
    else:
        break #Break if touching wall
key = win.getKey()
```

So, what do you guys think? Should I use a different library? Is there something sucking up time in my code? Or can I just not repeatedly draw to the screen in a reasonable timeframe?

I'm using an Acer Aspire E5-576G with an i5 processor and 8 gigs of RAM.

Comment: You don't have to guess. Measure the time, then comment out both `win.plotPixel`, then measure again, and you'll know if it's there or not. :) (Also, your inner `if` can be one-liner `antDir = antDir % 4 + 1`.)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it does seem to be the plotPixel - Is there a faster library you recommend?